# Run Boot2Docker from bash

Tags: macos, bash, docker, boot2docker

I have installed Boot2Docker on my Mac. By clicking on the app icon, a terminal window opens with some bash script running to prepare the docker vm and then you're good to go.

My problem is, I want to write a bash script to run the Boot2Docker vm and then run some docker's commands. Something along the lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

boot2docker start # WHAT SHOULD GO HERE?
docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888 --name {name} -v /src:/src image
```

What steps are taken when I click on the app icon so I can do manually in my bash script to prepare Boot2Docker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your `boot2docker start` with `boot2docker start && $(boot2docker shellinit)` and you are good to go. `$(boot2docker shellinit)` will export all the Environment variables needed.